# Method that receives a json and returns the two fields that come from the json and do the reverse

Tags: c#, .net, json, dictionary, json.net

Basically, I want to do a method that create and return an generic object (C#) with the two fields of the JSON

**Object**

```
{"value": 1, "type": "int"}
{"value": "true", "type": "boolean"}
{"value": "dfsfd", "type": "string"}
{"value": "31/03/2020", "type": "datetime"}
```

Comment: Thats not valid JSON

Comment: 1) That looks like [newline delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/) not JSON.  2) Could you clarify your question please?  You wrote *i want to do a method that create and return an object with the two fileds of the JSON* but it's hard to understand what you mean by that.  Also, your JSON sample looks odd,  `{"value": "sds", "type": "boolean"}` claims to be boolean but `"sds" is a string not a boolean.  Can you please [edit] your question your question to show real input data and the desired real output data?  As it is, your question might get closed as needing clarification.

Comment: {"value": "sds", "type": "boolean"} its the object. The idea is to transform a json into an object

Comment: What do you mean by *The idea is to transform a json into an object*?  `{"value": "true", "type": "boolean"}` is already a JSON object.  Are you just looking for [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842600/3744182)?

Comment: The idea its receive a json a return an oject with the two fields, Value and Type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is formatted wrong for one. It should look more like below.

**Option 1:**

```
{ "Classes": [
    {"value": "sdasd", "type": "int"},
    {"value": "sds", "type": "boolean"},
    {"value": "sd", "type": "string"},
    {"value": "sdds", "type": "datetime"}
]}
```

This is an object array in JSON. If this is the newline delimited JSON, honestly, I have no idea about that.

Next you will have to create a class that you will deserialize this JSON into.

```
public class CollectionOfMyClass
{
    public List<MyClass> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize using Newtonsoft.Json

```
    public CollectionOfMyClass GetCollection(string jsonString)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionOfMyClass>(jsonString);
    }
```

**Option 2:** this is a more generic approach

Json:

```
[
    {"value": "sdasd", "type": "int"},
    {"value": "sds", "type": "boolean"},
    {"value": "sd", "type": "string"},
    {"value": "sdds", "type": "datetime"}
]
```

Deserializing with Newtonsoft.JSON:

```
    public List<Dictionary<object, object>> GetCollection1(string jsonString)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<object, object>>>(jsonString);
    }
```

Comment: I thought of something like a dictionary. Deserialize json and save the key(type) and value(Value).

Comment: Maybe... let me try that real quick

Comment: See my edit. I added a way to deserialize into a list of dictionary<object, object>. Does this better suit you? It would take a little more work but this could be changed into a single dictionary as long as none of the keys match.